# Nested initComponent not working

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

I have a window(Ext.window.Window) in which I have pane in card layout. I am adding grid dynamically to the panels item as:

```
Ext.define('Example.view.ProcessInfoLayout',{
   extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    requires: [
        'Ext.layout.container.Card',
        'Example.view.SubProcessController',
        'Example.view.Info'
    ],
    xtype: 'app--processinfolayout',

    controller: 'main-content-subprocesscontroller',
    layout: 'fit',
    initComponent: function(){

       this.callParent();

        this.header = {
            titlePosition: 0,
            items:[{
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Resubmission',
                glyph: 'xf0e2@FontAwesome',
                tooltip: 'Resubmit',
                listeners: {
                    click: 'ResubmissionClick'
                }
            }]
        };
        console.log('thisw')


        this.items =  []

        this.add({
            xtype: 'panel',
            frame: false,
            border: false,
            itemId: 'v6panel',

            layout: {
                type:'card',
                deferredRender: true
            },

           defaultListenerScope: true,

           bbar: ['->',
                {
                    itemId: 'card-prev',
                    text: '&laquo; Previous',
                    handler: 'showPrevious',
                    disabled: true
                },
                {
                    itemId: 'card-next',
                    text: 'Next &raquo;',
                    handler: 'showNext'
                }
            ],

            items: [],
            initComponent: function() {
                var me = this;
                me.callParent();



                me.store = Ext.getStore('app-main-store-' + me.up('app-main-processinfolayout').processData.id);

                if (!me.store) {
                    me.store = Ext.create('Example.store.ProcessInfo', {
                        storeId: 'app-main-store-' + me.up('app-main-processinfolayout').processData.id,
                        room: me.up('app-main-processinfolayout').processData.id
                    });

                    me.store.proxy.url = Ext.String.format(me.store.proxy.url, 
                                                           me.up('app-main-processinfolayout').processData.id);
                }




              me.store.on('load', function(store, records, successful, eOpts) {
                console.log('@@@@')
                me.fireEvent('refreshProcessInfoLayoutView', me, records);
              });

            },

            listeners:{
                beforerender: function(obj) {
                    console.log('Hey Australia')
                    obj.store.load();
                },
                refreshProcessInfoLayoutView: 'refreshProcessInfoLayoutView',

               scope: 'this'


            },
            refreshProcessInfoLayoutView: function(obj, records) {
                console.log('thise')
                console.log(records[0].data.processes)
                    if (records[0].data.v6_processes) {
                        for (elem in records[0].data.processes) {
                            var subprocessInfo = {
                                xtype: 'app-main-cycle-info',
                                processId: records[0].data.processes[elem],
                                itemId: 'card-' + elem
                            };
                            obj.add(subprocessInfo);
                        }
                }
            },

            showNext: function () {
                this.doCardNavigation(1);
            },

            showPrevious: function (btn) {
                this.doCardNavigation(-1);
            },

            doCardNavigation: function (incr) {
                var me = this;
                var l = me.getLayout();
                var i = l.activeItem.id.split('card-')[1];
                var next = parseInt(i, 10) + incr;
                l.setActiveItem(next);

                me.down('#card-prev').setDisabled(next===0);
                me.down('#card-next').setDisabled(next===this.down('#v6panel').store.getCount() - 1);
            }
        })


    }
})
```

It prints console log upto thisw . After that it gives error as...Uncaught TypeError: me.items.insert is not a function. What I am doing wrong. Please suggest.

Comment: you have to pass arguments to this.callParent() like this this.callParent(arguments) otherwise it won't work

Comment: I have passed the arguments but still it givesthe same issue

Comment: then use to Ext.apply to apply new properties. don't use nested incompoenents it will not work. only once only it will be called

Comment: `callParent()` won't work if you're trying to modify `initComponent` on an instance. I'd suggest you rethink your approach.

Comment: here I am adding the panel to the window and than based on some data I am adding the grid to the panel in card layout. Should I go for this approach : I will create one panel.js there I will add all the grids and then in window.js I will add that panel as an item.  @Evan

Comment: Why modify initComponent of the instance at all? Doesn't really make sense. Just move the logic out into the owning class and pass it in as the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do `this.callParent();` in your `initComponent` before specifying `this.header` and `this.items`. Do it *after*. This is because once you've called `this.callParent();` your component is instantiated, therefore trying stuff like `this.items = []` just screws things up.

Also, instead of:

```
this.items = [];
this.add({stuff});
```

do:

```
this.items = [{stuff}];
```

Comment: If I modify the code according to the above comments It gives error as ...Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Your problem is easy to fix but hard to locate without seeing it in action. Consider posting a fiddle.

Comment: What I think ..Its not able to add panel to the window

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with nested items and `initComponent` functions, you can use the `xhooks` config so that `callParent()` can work properly :

```
Ext.define('Example.view.ProcessInfoLayout', { 
    // ...
    xhooks: {
        initComponent: function(){
            this.callParent();
            // ...
            this.add({
                xtype: 'panel',
                // ...
                items: [],
                initComponent: function() {
                    // ...
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Have a look at the [Ext.Component constructor method](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/source/Component2.html#Ext-Component-method-constructor).